# (The Triangle class) Design a class named Triangle that extends GeometricObject

Tags: java, inheritance

The class contains:

- Three **double** data fields named **side1**, **side2**, and **side3** with default values **1.0** to denote three sides of the triangle
- A no-arg constructor that creates a triangle with specified **side1**, **side2**,and **side3**.
- The accessor methods for all three data fields.
- A method named **getArea()** that returns the area if this triangle.
- A method named **getPerimeter()** that returns the perimeter of this triangle.

*A method named **toString()** that returns a string description for the triangle.

For the formula to compute the area of a triangle, see ProgrammingExercise 2.15( in An introduction to java programming 9th edition)
The **toString()** method is implemented as follows:

return " Triangle: side1 = " + side1 + " side2 = " + side2 + " side3 " + side3;

Draw the UML diagrams for the classes **Triangle** and **GeometricObject** and implement the classes. Write a test program that prompts the user to enter three sides of the triangle, a color, and a boolean value to indicate wheter the triangle is filled. The program should create a **triangle** object with these sides and set the **color** and **filled** properties using the input. The program should display the area, perimeter, color and true or false to indicate wheter it is filled or not.

---

The part of the exercise that i am having trouble with is the test program.

If you could help me out by giving me pointers about how i can make the Triangle from the input i would be very grateful.

The code i have at the moment is this :

**The GeometricObject**

```
public class GeometricObject {
    private String color = " white ";
    private boolean filled;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;

    public GeometricObject() {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }

    public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;   
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean isFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Created on " + dateCreated + "\n color: " + color + " and filled ";                 
    }   
 }
```

**The Triangle program**

```
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
    private double side1 = 1.0;
    private double side2 = 1.0;
    private double side3 = 1.0;

    public Triangle() {
    }

    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
    }

    public double setSide1() {
        return side1;
    }

    public double setSide2() {
        return side2;
    }

    public double setSide3() {
        return side3;
    }

    public void setSide1(double side1) {
        this.side1 = side1;
    }

    public void setSide2(double side2) {
        this.side2 = side2;
    }

    public void setSide3(double side3) {
        this.side3 = side2;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return side1 + side2 + side3;
    }

    public String toString() {
    return " Triangle: Side 1 = " + side1 + " Side 2 = " + side2
           + " Side 3 = " + side3;
    }
}
```

**The Testprogram.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestTriangle  {
    private double side1 = 1.0;
    private double side2 = 1.0;
    private double side3 = 1.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter three sides of the Triangle");
        double side1 = input.nextDouble();
        double side2 = input.nextDouble();
        double side3 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the color of the Triangle");
        String color = input.next();

        System.out.println(" Is the Triangle filled? Reply with 'True' or 'False' ");

        String filled = input.next(); 
    }
    {
        new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
        //How do i get the information into theTriangle?

        System.out.println("The Triangle Sides are \n side 1: " + side1 + "\n Side 2: " + side2 + "\n Side 3: " + side3);
        System.out.println("The Triangle's Area is " + (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2);
        System.out.println("The Triangle's Perimeter is "
                           + (side1 + side2 + side3));
        System.out.println("The Triangle's Color is " + //what goes here?);
        System.out.println("Is the Triangle filled? " + //what goes here?);

    }
}
```

Comment: `new Triangle(side1, side2, side3)`?

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the fast reply.
I added the code you suggested, now i'm closer to my goal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `Triangle` object like this, so that you have a reference

```
Trangle triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);

  //     ^^^^^^ This is the most important thing you're missing.  You need a reference
  //            point for your object.  That's the only way you can access it's
  //            properties.
```

You also need to set it's `filled` and `color` properties

```
triangle.setFilled(filled);
triangle.setColor(color);
```

Then, you can invoke its methods like this:

```
System.out.println("The Triangle Sides are \n side 1: " 
       + triangle.getSide1() + "\n Side 2: " + triangle.getSide2() 
       + "\n Side 3: " + triangle.getSide3());

System.out.println("The Triangle's Area is " + triangle.getArea());

System.out.println("The Triangle's Perimeter is " + triangle.getPerimeter();

System.out.println("The Triangle's Color is " + triangle.getColor());
System.out.println("Is the Triangle filled? " + triangle.isFilled());
```

You're able to access the `GeometricObject`'s `isFilled()`, `setFilled()`, `getColor()`, and `setColor()` because a `Triangle` is a `GeometricObject` (`extends`), so it inherits all its methods.

By the way, this is not how to calculate the area of a triangle:

```
public double getArea() {
    return (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;   // This is so wrong
}
```

Check out this [link](http://www.mathopenref.com/heronsformula.html) for correct formula

**Edit: With another problem with code**

```
public double setSide1() {
    return side1;
}

public double setSide2() {
    return side2;
}

public double setSide3() {
    return side3;
}

/**** Should Be ******/

public double getSide1() {
    return side1;
}

public double getSide2() {
    return side2;
}

public double getSide3() {
    return side3;
}
```

Edit: Triangle Formula

```
public double getArea() {
    int p = getPerimeter() / 2
    return Math.sqrt(p * ((p - side1) * (p - side2) * (p - side3));
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.

Both the color and filled is giving me errors.

`Triangle triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
  triangle.setFilled(filled);
  triangle.setColor(color);`

Also all the `triangle.getSide())`

in `System.out.println("The Triangle Sides are \n side 1: " + triangle.getSide1() + "\n Side 2: " + triangle.getSide2() + "\n Side 3: " + triangle.getSide3())´

Comment: Also, can i use the `getColor()`, `setColor()`,`isFilled()` , `setFilled()` from `GeometricObject` when i need to make the triangle based on input?

Comment: Okay, the errors i get now are _these_:

**On these lines**
`System.out.println("The Triangle Sides are \n side 1: "  + triangle.getSide1() + "\n Side 2: " + triangle.getSide2() + "\n Side 3: " + triangle.getSide3());`

**- The method getSide1() is undefined for the type 
  Triangle
- The method getSide2() is undefined for the type 
  Triangle
 The method getSide3() is undefined for the type 
  Triangle**

Comment: Aha! Thank you. Almost there now :)

Comment: You have `SIX` `set` methods in your triangle class.  Three of them should be `get` methods. That should solve your problem. Please accept this answer.

Comment: See my extended edit to see what I'm talking about with the `get` methods

Comment: Also, don't forget to fix your area formula.

Comment: So the area formula will not be `public double getArea() {
  return (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;`

but `public double getArea() {
  return Math.sqrt(side1 * side2 * side3) / 2;` ?

Comment: I'm saying the mathematical formula for the area of a triangle is not (side1 * side2 * side3) / 2.  Check out this link for correct formula http://www.mathopenref.com/heronsformula.html

Comment: I'm still having a bit of trouble regarding the formula for the area of a triangle.

This is the formula: A = sqrt p * (p - side1) * (p - side2) * (p - side3)

where p is **half** the perimeter.

Is this code anywhere near the desired outcome?

`public double getArea() {
  return Math.sqrt(getPerimeter() / 2) * (getPerimeter() / 2) - side1 * (getPerimeter() / 2) - side2 * (getPerimeter() / 2) - side3;`

Answer (score 0):

**GeometricObject**

```
package geometricobject;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Kirubel 
 */

abstract class GeometricObject
{

private String color = "white";
private boolean filled;
private java.util.Date dateCreated;
/** Construct a default geometric object */
protected GeometricObject()
{


}

/** Construct a geometric object with color and filled value */
protected GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled)
{
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    this.color = color;
    this.filled = filled;
}

/** Return color */
public String getColor()
{
    return color;
}

/** Set a new color */
public void setColor(String color)
{
    this.color = color;
}

/** Return filled. Since filled is boolean ,
 * the get method is named isFilled */
public boolean isFilled()
{
    return filled;
}

/** Set a new filled */
public void setFilled(boolean filled)
{
    this.filled = filled;
}

/** Get dateCreated */
public java.util.Date getDateCreated()
{
    return dateCreated;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "created on " + dateCreated + "\ncolor: " + color +
            " and filled: " + filled;
}

/** Abstract method getArea */
public abstract double getArea();

/** Abstract method getPerimeter */
public abstract double getPerimeter();

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

}
```

**Triangle**

```
class Triangle extends GeometricObject
{

public double side1;
public double side2;
public double side3;
public Triangle() //default constructor
{
    side1=1.0;
    side2=1.0;
    side3=1.0;
}

public Triangle(double side1,double side2,double side3) //peremetrised constructor
{
    this.side1=side1;
    this.side2=side2;
    this.side3=side3;
}
@Override
public double getPerimeter() //function for getting peremeter for triangle
{
    return(side1+side2+side3) ;

}



@Override
// function for getting area of triangle
public double getArea() 
{
    double area,s;
    s=side1+side2+side3;
    area = Math.sqrt(s * (s- side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3));
    return(area);

}
@Override
public String toString()//to print the data
{
    String s;
    s="Triangle:side1 "+ side1 +" side2 " + side2 + " side3 "+side3;
    return(s);
}

private String getSide1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private String getPerimeter(double d) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private String getPerimeter(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private String getSide3() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private String getSide2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


public static void main(String args[])
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter three sides of the Triangle");
    double side1 = input.nextDouble();
    double side2 = input.nextDouble();
    double side3 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter the color of the Triangle");
    String color = input.next();

    System.out.println(" Is the Triangle filled? Reply with 'True' or 'False' ");

    String filled = input.next(); 
}


{
    Triangle triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
    triangle.setFilled(isFilled());
    triangle.setColor(getColor());

    // Display 
    System.out.println("The Triangle Sides are \n side 1: " 
            + triangle.getSide1() + "\n Side 2: " + triangle.getSide2() 
            + "\n Side 3: " + triangle.getSide3());

    System.out.println("The Triangle's Area is " + triangle.getArea());
    System.out.println("The Triangle's Perimeter is " + triangle.getPerimeter());
    System.out.println("The Triangle's Color is " + triangle.getColor());
    System.out.println("Is the Triangle filled? " + triangle.isFilled());
}
}
```

Comment: after getting the  input from the user, it does not display the out come or the answer. 
  Sample Run #1:
 
Enter side 1 of triangle: 13 
Enter side 2 of triangle: 14 
Enter side 3 of triangle: 15 
Enter color of triangle: red 
Enter whether  triangle is filled (yes/no): yes 
Area: 84.0
Perimeter: 42.0
Color: red
Filled?: true 
Sample Run #2:


Enter side 1 of triangle: 9 
Enter side 2 of triangle: 40 
Enter side 3 of triangle: 41 
Enter color of triangle: orange 
Enter whether  triangle is filled (yes/no): no 
Area: 180.0
Perimeter: 90.0
Color: orange
Filled?: false